# Windows service stops down intermittantly

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, windows-services, parallel.foreach

I have a windows service which is used to monitor servers and services and on those services.

For this I am using two parallel.foreach loops the outer loop for servers and the inner loop for services on that particular server...... is this a right approach? I will be having around 400 servers and 10 services on each server so totally 4k computations on each iteration. But the the problem is windows service shuts down intermittently and doesn't record the data... I'm not sure if this is because of the load on the server. And also can you please suggest me what should be the minimum hardware configuration of the server on this this windows service runs. Code is as given below.

```
 public void CheckForWIServices()
        {

            List<ServiceMonitor> serviceMonitorList = new List<ServiceMonitor>();
            ConcurrentQueue<Exception> exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
            serverList = businessLayerObj.GetServerList();
            Parallel.ForEach(
                serverList,
                () => new Dictionary<string, List<ServiceMonitor>>(),
                (server, loop, localState) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        localState.Add(server.ServerName, serverServicesCheck(server));
                    }
                    catch (Win32Exception eEx)
                    {
                        exceptions.Enqueue(eEx);
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException Iex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Enqueue(Iex);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
                    }
                    return localState;
                },
                    localState =>
                    {
                        lock (serviceMonitorList)
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<ServiceMonitor>> item in localState)
                            {
                                var list = (List<ServiceMonitor>)item.Value;
                                foreach (ServiceMonitor serviceMonitor in list)
                                {
                                    serviceMonitorList.Add(serviceMonitor);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            businessLayerObj.SaveWIServices(serviceMonitorList);
            businessLayerObj.SetEndTimeWindowsService();
            //businessLayerObj.AddErrorToDbObject();
            businessLayerObj.SaveIndexTableChanges();
            //if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
            //return serviceMonitorList;
        }


public List<ServiceMonitor> serverServicesCheck(Server server)
        {
            List<Service> listOfServicesToBeMonitored = new List<Service>();
            List<ServiceMonitor> serviceMonitorList = new List<ServiceMonitor>();
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                listOfServicesToBeMonitored = businessLayerObj.GetListOfServicesMonitored(server);
            }
            if (listOfServicesToBeMonitored.Count > 0)
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(
                    listOfServicesToBeMonitored,
                    () => new List<ServiceMonitor>(),
                    (service, loop, localState) =>
                    {
                        if (service.ServiceType.ToLower() == "windows service")
                        {

                            localState.Add(new ServiceMonitor
                            {
                                CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                                ServerID = server.ServerID,
                                ServiceID = service.ServiceID,
                                ServiceStatus = CheckForWindowsService(server, service)
                            });
                        }
                        else if (service.ServiceType.ToLower().Contains("iis"))
                        {
                            localState.Add(new ServiceMonitor
                            {
                                CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                                ServerID = server.ServerID,
                                ServiceID = service.ServiceID,
                                ServiceStatus = CheckForIISServices(server, service)
                            });
                        }
                        return localState;
                    },
                        localState =>
                        {
                            lock (serviceMonitorList)
                            {
                                foreach (ServiceMonitor serviceMonitor in localState)
                                {
                                    serviceMonitorList.Add(serviceMonitor);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
            return serviceMonitorList;
        }



public bool CheckForWindowsService(Server server, Service service)
        {
            bool windowsService = false;

            try
            {
                windowsService = (new ServiceController(service.ServiceName, server.ServerName).Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //businessLayerObj.AddErrorObjectToStaticList(ex, server, service);
            }

            return windowsService;
        }

public bool CheckForIISServices(Server server, Service service)
        {
            bool windowsService = false;

            try
            {
                windowsService = ((ServerManager.OpenRemote(server.ServerName)).ApplicationPools[service.ServiceName].State == ObjectState.Started);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //businessLayerObj.AddErrorObjectToStaticList(ex, server, service);
            }

            return windowsService;

        }
```

Comment: Are you getting information about an exception in the event log?

Comment: Hmmmm.. no information in the event logs... and I'm trying to use async database logging component in windows service can anyone please suggest me any logging component....

Comment: Have you tried the Microsoft Patterns and practices Logging Application Block? It's pretty straight forward to configure and you can set listeners up to log out to various locations (event log, database, file etc..)